# How to access injected variables inside a derived class, while super() is not finished?

Tags: typescript

Why are injected variables not accessible in a TypeScript derived class method (member) unless the `super()` command is finished and returned? What if they are needed in the meanwhile?

I know that I have to call `super(...)` at first of its constructor, but if that super constructor is using one of the derived (child) overridden class methods how can I access those injected parameters in constructor?

For example, we know that a Set object is an iterable object that would not accept any duplicated item. For primitive values like integer or string, it is working fine, but when we need a Set of referenced type objects:

```
new Set([{a:1},{a:1}])
// Set(2) { { a: 1 }, { a: 1 } }
```

Obviously we don't want such output. and there is no way to override the compared method or pass any sort of predicate comparator for the sake of comparison. One solution might be:

```
class ObjSet<T> extends Set<T> {

  constructor(
    private eq: (self: T, other: T) => boolean,
    value: readonly T[] | Iterable<T> | null | undefined
  ) {
    super(value);
  }

  add(value: T): this {
    if (!this.eq) return super.add(value);
    for (const item of this) if (this.eq(item, value)) return this;
    return super.add(value);
  }

}
```

I'm passing a predicate function in the `constructor` and calling it in the overridden `add` method for the sake of comparison, if it returns true (there is a match) so do not add the new item to the `Set` if return false then add the new item by calling the `super.add(item)`.

Result of above code:

```
let setOfObjects = new ObjSet(
  (self, other) => self.a === other.a,
  [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }]
);

setOfObjects.add({ a: 1 });

console.log(setOfObjects.values());

//----------------------------------
// [Set Iterator] { { a: 1 }, { a: 2 } }
```

As you can see the overridden `add` method is working perfectly, but there is a problem:

```
let setOfObjects = new ObjSet(
  (self, other) => self.a === other.a,
  [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 1 }]
);

console.log(setOfObjects.values());

//----------------------------------
// [Set Iterator] { { a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 1 } }
```

The constructor doesn't work as we expect it to do, if one debugs the application he will see that in the derived constructor `eq` has value, then the `super(value)` will be called (which is the base class constructor) and inside the base/parent class, constructor will call the add method (from derived/child class).

Up to this point everything works as it should, but inside the `add` method since the `this` is actually the base class (`Set`) so `this.eq` is undefined.

Many alternatives that go around the problem but first I'd like to know, is there any solution for the described problem? And then I'd like to know what would be the cleanest way to make it work, two possible ways that I came up with might be:

```
// use comparator injected function to remove duplicate values in constructor while calling super()


  class ObjSet<T> extends Set<T> {
    constructor(
      public eq: (self: T, other: T) => boolean,
      value: readonly T[] | null | undefined
    ) {
      super(
        value
          ? value.reduce(
              (arr: any, x) =>
                arr.findIndex((y) => eq(x, y)) === -1 ? [...arr, x] : arr,
              []
            )
          : value
      );
    }

    add(value: T): this {
      if (!this.eq) return super.add(value);

      for (const item of this) if (this.eq(item, value)) return this;
      return super.add(value);
    }
  }
```

or:

```
declare global {
  interface Set<T> {
    eq: (self: T, other: T) => boolean;
  }
}

export function SetInitializer<T>(
  comparator: (self: T, other: T) => boolean,
  list: readonly T[] | Iterable<T> | null | undefined
) {
  Set.prototype.eq = comparator;

  class ObjSet<T> extends Set<T> {
    constructor(
      // public eq: (self: T, other: T) => boolean,
      value: readonly T[] | Iterable<T> | null | undefined
    ) {
      super(value);
    }

    add(value: T): this {
      // console.log(this.eq);

      if (!this.eq) return super.add(value);

      for (const item of this) if (this.eq(item, value)) return this;
      return super.add(value);
    }
  }

  return new ObjSet(list);
}
```

Comment: For _why_ just look at the [generated code](https://tsplay.dev/wR7LvN) - `super(value);` _then_ `this.eq = eq;`.

Comment: also I found this: "`super` calls the parent class's constructor and binds the parent class's public fields, after which the derived class's constructor can further access and modify `this`."
If anyone interested you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super#description)